# Why does Guard run ALL my RSpec specs on every change?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, guard

This testing stack is behaving unreliably. Sometimes when I run guard, it performs adequately with the guard-rspec gem and will only run the file that has been changed. At least, if the test fails it will stop with that single modified file.

But if that test passes, all bets are off. It will continue to run ***ALL*** tests when a single file is changed. On a good-sized application, this is extremely impractical and frustrating to see all tests run every time a file is saved.

My Guardfile is as follows. Notice that I had to change where it was pointing to RSpec specs. By default it thinks you are going to have a `specs` directory, and that all of your specs will be all jumbled into that one directory. I don't know anybody that tests like that, so it's a funny default to include. It should be looking for subdirectories under `specs`.

```
# A sample Guardfile
# More info at https://github.com/guard/guard#readme

guard 'spork', :cucumber => false, :rspec_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' } do
  watch('config/application.rb')
  watch('config/environment.rb')
  watch('config/environments/test.rb')
  watch(%r{^config/initializers/.+\.rb$})
  watch('Gemfile')
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb') { :rspec }
end

guard 'rspec', :version => 2, :cli => "--drb" do
  watch(%r{^spec/(.*)/(.+)_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

  # Rails examples
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml)$})                 { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
  watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
  watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }

  # Capybara features specs
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml)$})          { |m| "spec/features/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml)$})          { |m| "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }

  # Turnip features and steps
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/(.+)\.feature$})
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/steps/(.+)_steps\.rb$})   { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'spec/acceptance' }
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The guard-rspec gem has a parameter which controls whether all tests are run after a successful test.  It defaults to true, but can be changed to false to get the behavior you're looking for.

See the :all_after_pass option at https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec

Comment: I know, I have that set and it still doesn't work. ```guard 'rspec', :all_on_start => false, :all_after_pass => false, :version => 2, :cli => "--drb" do
```.

Comment: That's odd. The gem code is pretty straightforward, with the run_all call clearly dependent on that parameter. See line 98 at https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec/blob/master/lib/guard/rspec.rb  Are you sure it's picking up the Guardfile you think it is?

Comment: Same here, I have  guard 'cucumber', :cli => "--verbose --color --drb --format 'pretty'", :all_on_start => false, :all_after_pass => false  do and  guard 'rspec', :version => 2, :all_on_start => false, :all_after_pass => false, :cli => '--drb --color' do
 but still all the tests run after failures

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of reference, the `all_on_start: false` and `all_after_pass: false` options need to be set for each guard block. It took me awhile to finally figure out why mine behaving the same way.