# Guard RSpec Not Stopping After First Fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard, spork

Hey I cannot seem to get guard to stop running all my tests after the first test failure. I have seen this issue elsewhere on StackOverflow, here is the link to someone saying they did the same thing [Similar Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360618/why-does-guard-run-all-my-rspec-specs-on-every-change)  and still had the issue. Hoping someone can clear this up for me. My Guardfile is below:

```
require 'active_support/inflector'

guard 'spork', :cucumber_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' }, :rspec_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' } do
  watch('config/application.rb')
  watch('config/environment.rb')
  watch('config/environments/test.rb')
  watch(%r{^config/initializers/.+\.rb$})
  watch('Gemfile')
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb') { :rspec }
  watch('test/test_helper.rb') { :test_unit }
  watch(%r{features/support/}) { :cucumber }
end

guard 'rspec', all_on_start: false, after_all_pass: false, cli: '--fail-fast --drb' do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

#Custom Rails Tutorial specs
watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$}) do |m|
["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb",
 "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb",
 "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb",
 (m[1][/_pages/] ? "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" :
                   "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb")]
end
watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/}) do |m|
(m[1][/_pages/] ? "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" :
                  "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb")
end
watch(%r{^app/controllers/sessions_controller\.rb$}) do |m|
"spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb"
end


# Rails example
watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml)$})                 { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }

# Capybara features specs
watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml)$})          { |m| "spec/features/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }

# Turnip features and steps
watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/(.+)\.feature$})
watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/steps/(.+)_steps\.rb$})   { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'spec/acceptance' }
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have guard 'rspec' nested inside the other guard 'rspec'?

Comment: No, I'm doing my first rails tutorial. I went and deleted the 2nd "guard 'rspec' do" and the problem persists.

Answer (score 6):

All you need to do is set fail_fast option:

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.fail_fast = true
end
```